# How to print basic Christmas Tree with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, data-structures, tree

Trying to make a simple script that draws a tree of certain height in console with simple JS loops. It should look like that.

For height = 4 :

```
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

so far have this but somehow it's not working:

```
function drawTree(height) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < height ; i++ ) {
        var star = '*';
        var space = ' ';

        for ( var j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) {
            star = star + '***';            
        }

        for ( var k = height - 1 ; k > 0; k-- ) {            
            spacesBefore = space.repeat(k);
            star = spacesBefore + star;
        }
        console.log(star);
    }
}

var levels = prompt('How many levels high should be the tree?');

drawTree(levels);
alert('Check console')
```

any advice where I'm wrong? thx <3

Comment: Hello. "It's not working" is not a question. Please be a little more specific and include some of your own analysis or debugging attempts.

Comment: In the future, you should figure out the math before trying to write the program. It makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had 2 minor problems with your code.

1. There should be an odd number of stars per level (1, 3, 5, 7, ...) and you were adding 3n + 1 stars which will alternate between even and odd. The change to make for that is `star = star + "**"` instead of `... + "***"`
2. There is no need for the `for (var k = ...)` loop for counting the spaces. Your logic is right, but looping over the entire height for each row will yield you the same number of spaces per row, which is what your output is showing, which is wrong. What you want to do instead for the number of spaces is `height - i - 1`.

A working solution would look like the following:

```js
function drawTree(height) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < height ; i++ ) {
        var star = '*';
        var space = ' ';

        for ( var j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) {
            star = star + '**';            
        }
           
        var spacesBefore = space.repeat(height-i-1);
        star = spacesBefore + star;
        console.log(star);
    }
}

var levels = prompt('How many levels high should be the tree?');

drawTree(levels);
```

A more concise version of this code would look like the following:

```js
function drawTree(height) {
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    // 2n+1 stars per row i.e. 1, 3, 5, 7, ...
    var stars = '*'.repeat(2 * i + 1);
    var spacesBefore = ' '.repeat(height - i - 1);
    console.log(spacesBefore + stars);
  }
}

drawTree(prompt('How many levels high should be the tree?'));
```

Comment: it indeed is working :) thanks ! i was too stubborn that i need 2nd loop, while this is much cleaner

Comment: @Cienszki I added a more concise version if you're interested. The inner `for (var j ...)` loop is also unnecessary, you can just use `.repeat()` just like you do with the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to calculate width first and then use that width. Spaces are depended upon width and number of `*` in each height.

```
width = height*2 - 1;
```

Code for tree:

```
function tree(h) {

    let i =0, j = 1;

    w = h*2 - 1;

    let space = parseInt(w / 2);

    while (space >= 0) {
        let str = '';

        for (i = 0; i < space; i++) str += ' ';

        for (i = 0; i<j; i++) str += '*';

        console.log(str);

        // Since every next line got 2 more *
        j += 2;
        // Number of space reduce by 1
        space--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function drawTree(h) {
    let star = "*";
    let space = " ";
    let spaceCount = h-1;
    let starCount = 1;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        console.log(`${space.repeat(spaceCount)}${star.repeat(starCount)}${space.repeat(spaceCount)}`);
        spaceCount -= 1;
        starCount += 2;
    }
}

drawTree(20)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).